# Can not access List<string> from another class

Tags: c#

I am trying to access the List declared in ImageCollection Class. Here is the code.

```
class ImageCollection
{
    public List<string> imgCollection = new List<string>();       

    public void addImgCollection(string path)
    {
        imgCollection.Add(path);
    }

    public List<string> getList()
    {
        return imgCollection;
    }
}
```

And add the image path into imgCollection from AutoClass using this code.

```
ImageCollection imgcoll = new ImageCollection();
imgcoll.addImgCollection(img1);
imgcoll.addImgCollection(img2);
```

But, when I access the List from MainForm:

```
ImageCollection image = new ImageCollection();
List<string> imgcol = image.getList();
```

The result is empty.
What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You are instantiating again, so it becomes null

Comment: It isn't null but empty.

Comment: Because you create new empty ImageCollection. But it can't be null it is just empty.

Comment: Yes i mean it's empty. thank you. so what should i do so it doesn't get empty

Comment: @puspita: when you create an instance of your class all fields are initialized with their default value. Since you are initializing the list inline it will be an empty list. If you want to share this collection across all instances you could make it `static`.

Comment: Yes it works when I make it static, I just curious why it doesn't work using instance. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: it's not good question, naturally you will get empty list due to you did not add any item in  imgCollection

Comment: You have to pass the `imgcol1` variable as a parameter to the place where You call `image.getList()`. And call `imgcol1.getList()` instead, and don't do `ImageCollection imgcol1 = new ImageCollection()` at the second place. This way, the same instance is asked for the collection, not a new instance.

Answer (score 1):

Here you create a **new** instance of ImageCollection. That's why it's property imgCollection has it's default value (which is `null )` :

```
ImageCollection image = new ImageCollection();
List<string> imgcol = image.getList();
```

I believe that what you tried to do is :

```
public class AutoClass 
{
   public static ImageCollection imgcol1 = new ImageCollection();

   // somewhere in your AutoClass:
      imgcoll.addImgCollection(img1);
      imgcoll.addImgCollection(img2);   
}
```

Then you can do from your MainForm class :

```
// copies collection to imgcol (therefore creates a new collection with samve values)
List<string> imgcol = AutoClass.imgcol1.imgCollection.ToList(); 

// saves reference to ImgCollection collection to imgcol variable (not copying anything)
List<string> imgcol = AutoClass.imgcol1.imgCollection;
```

If you don't want to use static property you can use instance property instead :

```
public class AutoClass 
{
   public ImageCollection imgcol1 = new ImageCollection();

   // somewhere in your AutoClass:
      imgcoll.addImgCollection(img1);
      imgcoll.addImgCollection(img2);   
}
```

And in your MainForm :

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    AutoClass ac = new AutoClass();

    ...

    void MyMethod
    {
        List<string> imgcol = ac.imgcol1.imgCollection; 
        // (you don't really need this GetList method of AutoClass at all)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please mention also a solution, that is using parameter passing. Without the need of static, just pass the `imgcol1` variable as an argument on an imaginary call chain.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is first line here:

```
ImageCollection image = new ImageCollection();
List<string> imgcol = image.getList();
```

You're creating new instance of ImageCollection class, so its imgCollection property becomes empty again.

In your AutoClass you should expose ImageCollection instance to your MainForm.

It would look more or less like that

```
public class AutoClass
{
       public ImageCollection Imgcoll { get; set; }

       public AutoClass()
       {
              Imgcoll = new ImageCollection();
       }

       public void SomeMethod(someargs)
       {
              Imgcoll.addImgCollection(img1);
              Imgcoll.addImgCollection(img2);
       }
}
```

And then in MainForm:

```
//autoClassInstance should be somewhere initialized and defined within MainForm
List<string> imgcol = autoClassInstance.ImgColl.getList();
```

Moreover please take a look at Naming Guidelines by Microsoft - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx - because you name instances and methods in a wrong way.